# How can I slide image onmouseover link programmatically

Tags: jquery, html, css

I try to prepare a simple work portfolio. I select works programmatically from database. I just want to do on mouse over a work change background image of div.

```
<div>
    <div style="width:100%; position:absolute;">
    <ul>
    <li style="background-image:url(1.png);"></li>
    <li style="background-image:url(2.png);"></li>
    <li style="background-image:url(3.png);"></li>
    </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <a href="#">WORK 1</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <a href="#">WORK 2</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <a href="#">WORK 3</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

On above ul li tags these are my images when I mouse over links on bottom i will slide one of them. How can I slide images. Should I identitiy every li tag?

Comment: Css should suffice for this, with hover

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add identifiers to your work-items. Like work_1, work_2 etc. And add a class to every item.

```
<div>
    <div style="width:100%; position:absolute;">
    <ul>
    <li id="work_1" class="work-item" style="background-image:url(1.png);"></li>
    <li id="work_2" class="work-item" style="background-image:url(2.png);"></li>
    <li id="work_3" class="work-item" style="background-image:url(3.png);"></li>
    </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <a href="#" data-show="work_1">WORK 1</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <a href="#" data-show="work_2">WORK 2</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <a href="#" data_show="work_3">WORK 3</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

With every hover on each item you hide all items, and show the one your element is linked to.

```
<script>
$('.work_hover').mouseover(function() {
    var id_to_show = $(this).attr('show');
    $('.work-item').hide();
    $('#' + id_to_show).show();
});
</script>
```

To finish the slider you can add cool animations to the show and hide methods

Comment: Thanks for quick reply but it doesn't work. Should i put javascript inside of document ready?